# pip adds all subdirectories into site-packages?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a Python project `testpkg` organized like:

```
.
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
├── testpkg/
|    |-- __init__.py
│    └── package1/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module.py
└── tests/
    ├── test1.py
```

After installing with

`python -m pip install .`

both the `testpkg` and `package1` directory get added to my `site-packages`.

Therefore my `site-packages` will have

```
site-packages/testpkg
site-package/package1
```

How can I just make `testpkg` end up in my `site-packages`?

**What I tried:**
I made a dummy project with the structure shown above, and tried using pip to install locally. I expected that only the `testpkg` directory gets added to `site-packages`.

My setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pathlib import Path

setup(
    name="testpkg",
    version="1.0.0",
    description="Description",
    download_url="https://github.com/path/to/repo",
    author="Me",
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    packages=find_packages(include=["testpkg", "testpkg.*"]),
    install_requires=[
        "numpy",
    ],
    zip_safe=True,
)
```

My pyproject.toml file:

```
[build-system]
requires = ['setuptools>=42']
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
```

Comment: Package directories are defined in setup.py and the toml file. What's in them?

Comment: @tdelaney I added the setup.py and toml file

Comment: You need to add `testpkg/__init__.py`

Comment: @ykhrustalev forgot to list it there, but `testpkg/__init__.py`  does exist.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting both packages and installing again, it might be a leftover from your previous experiments, your setup looks correct

Comment: @ykhrustalev Thank you, that fixed it. There must have been something left over...